# ActiveRecord's weird timezone handling when Daylight Saving Time changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord

I have an application providing agenda functionalities.

*Disclaimer: I really love Rails and AR's functionalities, this is just meant to ask how can I exploit it functionalities better the next time.*

Since it has to be used by a european team it has been developed using +0200 timing informations. I know that the timezone stuff is handled by AR and the base data is always stored in UTC.

The issue I get (but I already solved, just wanted to get some feedback to think it better the next time) is that when I store a new appointment I also enforce "+0200" at the end of the `DateTime.parse` call (es. `DateTime.parse("#{day} #{hour} +0200")` and then I set it as record attribute. Of course `10:00` gets stored as `08:00` inside the data layer, and that's fine.

Then when I retrieve that data using the configured AR timezone (`Rome` for instance) using something like `@appointment.start_at` it correctly gets converted back when we are under the CEST daylight time. Issues start happening when `start_at` are set to be CET (+0100) dates (but I always store it inside the database enforcing CEST +0200).

Inside the database `start_at` is always the same, so the UTC representation is always `08:00` when saving an appointment with `10:00` but the AR conversion uses the wrong daylight conversion (CET).

I know I could skip this by simply working all on UTC so I don't have to carry out any consideration about daylight savings times, but it seems a bit messy that AR itself is not able to remember somehow that I stored it while CEST is running.

When performing queries I do the same as when storing, so I append "+0200" to all DateTimes, and all works back again, but when displaying I need to check whether the TimeZone is "CET" or "CEST" and add a `+1.hour` to CET (otherwise it results the appointment has been signed 1 hour before than the intended hour).

1. Is it right I should handle this by myself?
2. Shouldn't be AR able to perform this kind of check since it wraps the data-layer?
3. How should I design an application the next time to avoid this kind of issue while still using local timezones? (as I said using UTC may also not be applicable by some requirements)

I thought I should change "+0200" with "in_time_zone" the next time, but I also allow users to write by hand an hour to search, and of course this will always be the same time either it is "CET" or "CEST" and of course I cannot enforce users to write following the UTC format.

Thank you,

Comment: Dealing with the same issue, but checking for daylight time isn't an option because I need to handle all timezones. Very well written, and I'll check back if I find anything relevant!